# Hide Browser's vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, ng-dialog

I am using an ngDialog for popups. I am trying to make the dialog window as tall as possible. But at some point it will trigger a vertical scrollbar in Browser's window. I am attaching an image that illustrates that. I have tried overflow:hidden on an html element, on body element - nothing helps. Give me soome ideas please.
[image]

I tried this:

```
<html ng-app="app" style="height:100%;overflow:auto">
<body style="overflow: hidden" scroll="no">
```

It did not help.

My ngDialog style is this:

```
<style>
.ngdialog-overlay {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#333333;
    background:rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ngdialog.dialogcaseeditor .ngdialog-content {
    width: 95%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}    
</style>
```

Somewhere down the road I have the following to make the dialog as tall as possible:

```
$dialog.dialog.find('.ngdialog-content').css('height', $window.innerHeight - 50);
```

That will make it nicely fit on the screen except the scrollbar on the lower right corner.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS

Comment: Seems, like it works fine in IE11, but not in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Here is what it takes to fix the problem in Chrome:

```
 $dialog.dialog.css('overflow', 'hidden');
```